# StopHotReload: Could not find project for MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.MonoDroid.MonoDroidDebuggerSession

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, hot-reload

I'm working on an Xamarin project for school using C# on VS2019. I'm limited to only using Android. I've been using the built in Android Device manager within VS for my Android Emulator. Hot Reload has been working great up until now. For some reason, my XAML changes are no longer displaying on the emulator immediately using hot Reload.

In the output window, I'm seeing this error `StopHotReload: Could not find project for MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.MonoDroid.MonoDroidDebuggerSession`. I haven't made any changes to the solution or updated any packages. Any ideas why it would just randomly stop working?

It's now working for either mode `Changes only(Xamarin.Forms 5.x and newer` or `Full Page`

Comment: My project must have gotten in a weird state. Closing and re-opening Visual Studio and rebooting the emulator seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This works.  Could you satisfy my.. er.. friend's OCD and make your comment an answer?